# Root user cannot read /root

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, root

I added a user called 'kma' to root group. Then I changed permission of /root/ to 770. Which should give the user read, write and execute access since I added him to the root group. But it still gives permission denied error. What am I doing wrong here?

Commands I executed:

```
sudo adduser kma root
sudo chmod 770 /root/
cd /root/ <------- Gives permission error
```

Comment: Have you started a new login session for user `kma`? the new group membership will not take effect in the current session

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to open a new shell.  The current shell won't automatically have the new group.  Log out and back in, or run `exec bash`.